# How can I prevent IO permission denied when I quickly read and write from txt

Tags: python, python-2.7, io, crash, ioerror

Strange things happens when I do this:

```
while True:
    with open('Test.log', "a") as log_txt:
        log_txt.write('Test.\n')
```

and then the program begins to run for a while and suddenly crashed!

The most strange thing is that it wasn't sure how many lines it will write! Sometimes it went on for several hundreds lines and sometime it was several thousands, then at some point it always crash, and then reply:

```
IOError:[Errno 13]Permission denied: 'Test.log'
```

No matter which path I put the code, it always crashed within a very short time. So I was wondering whether there is a multithreading thing that it doesn't close the log quick enough and then open it again?

And surprisingly I found that it also happens even I did some calculation between two writing.

```
# First writing

with open('IFM.log', "a") as log_text:
    log_text.write('Evaluating current_file: {}\n\n'.format(self._current_file.expression))
    log_text.write('IC: {}\n\n'.format(self._current_file.IC))

# Did some calculations

self._current_file.IC_adjusted = self._current_file.IC * \
                             (e - e ** (0.1 * self._current_file.complexity)) / (e - 1)

# Second writing

with open('IFM.log', "a") as log_text:
    log_text.write('IC_adjusted: {}\n\n'.format(self._current_file.IC_adjusted))
```

How can I fixed this? I don't want to do time.sleep()... It's so dumb...

Comment: What operating system are you using? Do you have a virus checker installed?

Comment: Some other program might be using the same file, that's why you get the permission denied error.

Comment: Windows 10, I shut all the other programs so I don't think it was the problem ……

Comment: And I use the company computer to run and same thing happens, so I don't think it was virus...

Comment: Virus checkers are notorious for this sort of thing. Whenever a program writes to a file, they open up the file in the background and read it to make sure it (still) doesn't have a virus. Yes, they even do this for text files. This can cause all sorts of problems like what you describe. Try to turn off or disable any virus checker you might have active.

Comment: @GregHewgill Seems that it is my virus checker who's messing with me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GregHewgill By the way can you recommend me a virus checker which can put my output file in the white list? My virus checker doesn't seems to have that function...

Answer (score -2):

The most realistic problem here might be that your code exceeded the # of available file descriptors in your OS.

As far as I know Python might not close the file immediately after the end of `with` block, but start executing the next `while` iteration immediately after.
And the file will be closed at some time in the future.

After a while there may be thousands of opened files... so => crash.

Comment: So how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Your hypothesis is not actually true. Python *will* close the file at the end of the `with` block. There is no "some time in the future" that this would happen - it's deterministic.

Comment: Try to close the file by hand, not rely on automatic solutions.